# Method local classes ?

Tags: java

When we declare a class inside a function and also create a variable of that class, is the object for that class pushed onto the stack or the heap ? I have some confusion regarding the use of final keywords when used in context with inner classes ? If both the variable and the class object exist on the stack, why do we then need to name a variable final ?

Kind Regards.

Comment: 1) Ask one question per question, or at least ask related questions. 2) Did you try googling this? Or reading the docs?

Comment: The only things stored on the stack in Java are primitives and references. Objects are always stored on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

> When we declare a class inside a function and also create a variable of that class, is the object for that class pushed onto the stack or the heap?

Your terminology is incorrect, and that is probably the root of your confusion:

- Declaration of a class does not cause any space to be allocated ... apart from one-time allocations of the space used to represent the code, statics, etc that happen when the class is loaded and initialized.
- Java has methods, not functions.
- When you declare an variable inside a method (i.e. a local variable), the space for the variable itself is allocated on the stack.  (If you declare a static or instance variable, the space will be part of a heap node.)
- When you create an instance of a class (i.e. an object), the space for that instance is allocated on the heap<sup>1</sup>.  The reference for that instance may be assigned to a *previously allocated* variable ... on the stack (for a local variable in a method) or heap (for a static or instance variable) ... but it could also be immediately discarded.  Either way, the allocation of space for the reference is independent of the creation of the instance.

> I have some confusion regarding the use of final keywords when used in context with inner classes ? If both the variable and the class object exist on the stack, why do we then need to name a variable final ?

The `final` is required because Java doesn't support proper closures.  What happens when an inner class refers to a *local* variable in an enclosing scope is that the value of the variable is passed to the inner class and stored in a hidden variable.  The `final` allows the compiler to effectively hide this from the application.  Since the application cannot change the contents of the variables, it cannot tell that there are two copies of the variable<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - This is a slight oversimplification.  Read up on "escape analysis" if you are interested.</sup>

<sup>2 - This is the exception to the rule that local variables are stored on the stack.  In this case, a copy of the variable is *also* stored in the heap node for the inner class instance.  However this is an implementation detail ... as is all stack-versus-heap stuff.  If the JVM architecture was changed to support closures, things would probably be different.</sup>

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "When you create an instance of a class (i.e. an object), the space for that instance is allocated on the heap1. The reference for that instance may be assigned to a previously allocated variable ... on the stack (for a local variable in a method) or heap (for a static or instance variable)"

Comment: I am using standard Java terminology and plain English.  If you don't understand, you will need to give me some clues about *what* you don't understand.